# Getting Unexpected mutation of "buttonText" prop

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, button

I have created simple component for button in vuejs,When I clicked on the button then the text should show "I have been clicked". and it does but with this I also getting error that say:   `49:7  error  Unexpected mutation of "buttonText" prop  vue/no-mutating-props`
I have tried with this.$emit() but didnot mange to fix the mutation error issue. Can someone explain me what I am doing wrong and why I cannot mutate the buttonText props. Any help will be much appreciated!
here is my code:

```
App.vue

<template>
 <div>
    <ButtonDisabled buttonText="ChangedText" />
   </div>

</template>
```

ButtonDisabled.vue:

```
<template>
  <div class="main-container">
    <h1>Button Disable if nothing is enter in email field</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" v-model="email" />
      <button :disabled="email.length < 1" class="btn-sub" @click="handleClick">
        Subcribe
      </button>
      <!-- <button :disabled="!email.length">Subscribe</button> -->
      <h2>{{ email }}</h2>
      <h1>{{ buttonText }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "ButtonDynamic",

  props: {
    buttonText: {
      type: String,
      default: "clickMe",
      required: false,
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      // this.$emit("change-text-onclick", this.buttonText);
      this.buttonText = "I have been clicked!!!";
    },
  },
};
</script>

<style scoped>
.main-container {
  width: 300px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.wrapper {
  display: inline-flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.btn-sub {
  margin: 10px;
}

</style>
```

Getting this error:

[image]

But my component still works when clicked:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Is it a bad practice to mutate a prop see [link](https://vuejs.org/guide/components/props.html#one-way-data-flow), you can mutate an inner component variable inside data or use v-model to have two-way dataflow on your props using [v-model](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/v-model.html).

in this case, you can:

1. set up your internal data variable with the value of your prop, and then mutate that data variable ( not the prop )
2. Create and set the prop as a model value and expose it with a emit.

I will show you the easier path to get out of the error, but you need to reconsider your component responsibilities.

```js
Vue.component('mybutton', {
  template: `
 <div class="main-container">
    <h1>Button Disable if nothing is enter in email field</h1>
    <div class="wrapper">
      <input type="email" placeholder="email" v-model="email" />
      <button :disabled="email.length < 1" class="btn-sub" @click="handleClick">
        Subcribe
      </button>
      <!-- <button :disabled="!email.length">Subscribe</button> -->
      <h2>{{ email }}</h2>
      <h1>{{ inputMessage }}</h1>
    </div>
  </div>
  `,
  props: {
    buttonText: {
      type: String,
      default: "clickMe",
      required: false,
    }
  },

  data() {
    return {
      email: "",
      inputMessage: this.buttonText
    };
  },

  methods: {
    handleClick() {
      this.inputMessage = "I have been clicked!!!";
    },
  },
});


new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data(){
     return {
        message: "Changed Text"
     }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>


<div id="app">
   <div>
      <mybutton button-text="Change Text" />
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hi JC, Thanks for the help, yes I should not have mutated the props directly, it was a silly mistake. Now I am not getting the Error :) But now I have second issue is that when i clicked on the Subscribe button then `handleClick() ` function doesnot work anymore.
Do i have to use the $emit() function here. Thanks in Advance!

Comment: I tried with $emit (), inside my handleClick() added this two lines:
`
 this.$emit("change-text-onclick", this.inputMessage);` and in App.vue, added:
`<ButtonDisabled
        :buttonText="this.btnMessage"
        v-on:change-text-onclick="changeTextOnClick($event)"
      />

and inside Methods: { 
changeTextOnClick(inputMessage) {
      console.log(inputMessage);
  inputMessage = "I have been Clicked now!!!";
    }, }
`
But when Clicked on Button nothing happens. its seems to me I am lost here :(

Comment: Tried this way  and its works now : )

```
changeTextOnClick(inputMessage) {
      console.log(inputMessage);
      this.btnMessageChange = inputMessage;
    },
```